# If $\{N_k\}_{k=1} \subset \Bbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers then $(N_k) \rightarrow \infty$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Need to prove:

If $\{N_k\}_{k=1} \subset \Bbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers
then $(N_k) \rightarrow \infty$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

I think I just need to show that a strictly increasing sequence is not bounded above so it has no max... but not sure how..

Comment: If your sequence admits a bound $B>0$, then it cannot have more than $\lceil B\rceil$ entries.

Comment: It is clear that $N_{k+1}-N_{k}\ge 1$, therefore $N_{k+1}\ge k+N_{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that since $N_1\geq1$ and $N_{k+1}>N_k$, we have that $N_k>k$, so the sequence is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the sequence doesn't diverge to infinity. Since it's a sequence of natural numbers, there must be some $M \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} N_k = M$. By the definition of convergence, this means for all $\epsilon >0$ there is some index $L \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $l > L$ we know $|N_l-M|< \epsilon$. Let's choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Then again there must exist some $L_\frac{1}{2} \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $l_\frac{1}{2}> L_\frac{1}{2}$ we have $|N_{l_{\frac{1}{2}}}-M|< \frac{1}{2}$ But this means $N_{l_{\frac{1}{2}}}=M$ because the difference between two different natural numbers is at least one: The difference cannot be less than $\frac{1}{2}$ unless the two numbers are equal. Thus, for all $l_\frac{1}{2}> L_\frac{1}{2}$, we have $N_{l_{\frac{1}{2}}}=M$, making $N_k$ an eventually constant sequence. This is obviously a contradiction, as we assumed we were working with a strictly increasing sequence. Thus, $(N_k) \rightarrow \infty$.